# How to pass values to a nodejs callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

So I'm trying to wrap my head around how i can pass variables/data to a callback sort of like how Request does it:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```

how do the developers pass the error, response, and body to the callback for the user to use? For instance, say I have a basic main function:

```
function main(_arg1, _arg2, callback) { ... }
```

and when i call it i would do something like

```
main('test1', 'test2', function(a, b){ console.log(a+b); }
```

correct? So how would i pass `_arg1` and `_arg2` to the callback so that it would output a result like `test1test2` ?

I tried looking all through stackoverflow but i couldn't find anything relating to this, so if this is a duplicate I'm sorry.

However, any help and/or explanation would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pass them as arguments when you call the callback.  Here's an example:

```
// define a function that accepts a callback argument
function callMeBackPlease(x, y, callback) {
    // call the callback and pass it the desired arguments
    callback(x+y, x/y);
}

// call the function and pass it a callback function
callMeBackPlease(3, 5, function(sum, div) {
    console.log(sum, div);  // outputs 8, 0.6
});
```

A callback is just a function.  And, in Javascript you can pass a function as an argument when calling some other function and the function it was passed to can then call that callback function with whatever arguments are appropriate.

Comment: okay thank you  for the clear and simple example instead of a long definition of callbacks like i've seen on some other questions. Sorry i know this was a very newbie question but i'm still trying to adjust to async programming

Comment: @AmouxTechnerd: *"instead of a long definition of callbacks like i've seen on some other questions"* A callback is just a function. That's all the definition you should need ;) "Callback" just describes a bit better what the purpose of the function is.